# Trato de actualizar una tabla mediante las lineas que tiene un datagridview y los valores se insertan vacíos

Tags: c#, sql-server

```
cnn.insertarimagen(textBox1.Text, pictureBox1);
```

Primero inserto una imagen a la tabla y un nombre a la imagen y luego trato de actualizar, pero los valores actualizan, pero los valores quedan vacíos no nulos sino vacíos, al parecer las variables que cree no llegan a tomar valores.

```
SqlCommand insertar = new SqlCommand("update reparaciones set [Codigo del Cliente]=@1,Nombres=@2,Apellidos=@3,Telefono=@4,Celular=@5,Dispositivo=@6,Modelo=@7,Color=@8,[Notas de Condiciones]=@9,[Reparaciones a Realizar]=@10,[Codigo Pieza]=@11,Descripcion=@12,Referencia=@13,Marca=@14,[Cantidad en Existencia]=@15,[Materiales de Reparacion]=@16,[Cantidad Vendida]=@17,[Compromiso de Entrega]=@18 where [Nombre de Imagen]='" + textBox1.Text + "'", con);
            con.Open();


            try
            {
                foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dtgv.Rows)
                {




                    insertar.Parameters.Clear();

                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@1", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column1"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@2", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column2"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@3", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column3"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@4", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column4"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@5", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column5"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@6", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column6"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@7", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column7"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@8", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column8"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@9", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column9"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@10", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column10"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@11", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column11"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@12", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column12"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@13", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column13"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@14", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column14"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@15", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column15"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@16", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column16"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@17", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column17"].Value));
                    insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@18", Convert.ToString(row.Cells["Column18"].Value));



                    insertar.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    con.Close();
                }
                MessageBox.Show("Transaccion realizada con Exito.");



            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error en la Transaccion." + ex);
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }
```

Comment: Entiendo que has comprobado que el datagridview tiene los valore correctos cuando vas realizando los updates. ¿Puede ser un problema de tipos de los parametros?

Comment: Otra cosa sin tener muchos datos, ¿No sería mas interesante enlazar el datagridview directamente con la tabla de la base de datos y que los datos se actualicen automáticamente?

Comment: gracias @Gerardo tratare con eso